# How can I capture the selected cell content in Excel file by Python?

Tags: python, excel

I want to realize a function: running a python script, then open a Excel file,select a cell by clicking the mouse,the running python script can get the selected content.

I try pywin32:GetwindowText:GetForegrondWindow,I only can get the title of the document. I also can get the mouse position by using pynput.But How can I get the selected cell conent in Excel file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have written some code for this logic, please do share that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you only want the value of a cell. It won't open the file and click on that cell.

**Command to install xlrd module :**

```
pip install xlrd
```

## Reading an excel file using Python

```
import xlrd
```

## Give the location of the file

```
loc = ("path of file")
```

## To open Workbook

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

## For row 0 and column 0

```
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you!@LeSaugave. I know the method of xlrd. what I really achieve is to establish an interactive process between the user and the program, we don't know what cell the user may want to select,therefore, it is a must by using a mouse to click to select the cell.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can write a macro in excel,and use python code call the macro.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).